# Creating a super user that is not able to access admin site

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating an admin user using the following code. However this user is unable to login. Any suggestions on why this user cant log in to the admin site

```
  user = User.objects.create(username = "joe",first_name="jordan", last_name="...", email="jordan@gmail.com", password="admin123",is_staff=True,is_superuser=True)
```

The username is `joe` and password is `admin123` however this user cant login

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django stores hashed passwords. Since you passed to DB plain password, Django could not authenticate user. You should use `set_password` when creating new user to hash password:

```
user = User(username = "joe",first_name="jordan", last_name="...", email="jordan@gmail.com",is_staff=True,is_superuser=True)
user.set_password("admin123")
user.save()
```

Or you can use `create_superuser` method:

```
user = User.objects.create_superuser(username = "joe",first_name="jordan", last_name="...", email="jordan@gmail.com", password="admin123")
```

Comment: @Rajeshwar No you didn't :)

Comment: I was waiting for the timer to clear up and then forgot about it :(